# computing the metric on a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M^n$ be a complex manifold with coordinates $z_1,\dots, z_n$ where $z_k=x_k+\sqrt{-1}y_k$. Let $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z_k}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}+\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}$$ and $$dz_k=dx_k+\sqrt{-1}dy_k \ \ \text{ and } \ \ d\overline z_k=dx_k+\sqrt{-1}dy_k.$$ Let $J$ be a complex structure on $M$ and let $g$ be a Hermitian metric. Let $$g_{j\overline k}=g\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z_j},\frac{\partial}{\partial\overline z_k}\right)$$ I am trying to understand how $g_{j\overline k}$ determines $g$. Is it true that

$$g=\sum_{j,k=1}^{2n}g_{jk}dx_j\otimes dy_k=\sum_{j,k=1}^ng_{i\overline k}(dz_j\otimes d\overline z_k +d \overline z_k\otimes dz_j)?$$

I seem to recall reading this somewhere, but can't find where now. If it is, is there an obvious reason why this holds?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}=\frac 12 \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k}\bigg)\ \ \text{ and } \ \ \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline z_k}=\frac 12 \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}+\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_k} \bigg)$$

will be a better convention, since we will then have

$$dz_i\bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial z_j} \bigg)= (dx_i+ \sqrt{-1} dy_i) \bigg(\frac 12\bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}-\sqrt{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\bigg)\bigg)= \frac 12 ( \delta_{ij} + \delta_{ij}) = \delta_{ij}$$

and similarly

$$d\overline{z_i}\bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z_j}} \bigg)= \delta_{ij}, \ \ \ d\overline{z_i}\bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial {z_j}} \bigg) =dz_i\bigg(\frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z_j}} \bigg) = 0. $$

(This notation is used in Griffiths and Harris's Principle of Algebraic Geometry).

Then the formula you asked for is just linear algebra: For any bilinear form $g: T^{\mathbb C}_pM \times T^{\mathbb C}_pM \to \mathbb C$, let $v_1, \cdots, v_{2n}$ be any complex basis of $T^{\mathbb C}_pM$ with dual basis $v_1^*, \cdots, v_{2n}^*$, then

$$g = \sum_{i=1}^{2n} g(v_i, v_j) v_i^* \otimes v_j^*.$$

(Of course we used that

$$ g\bigg( \frac{\partial }{\partial z_i} , \frac{\partial }{\partial z_j}\bigg) = g\bigg( \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z_i}} , \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z_j}}\bigg) = 0$$

here.)